# What's the meaning of a new quantum state vector obtained from an operator acting on original quantum state vector

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information

Let's say we have a single photon state vector, i.e., $\left|1\right>$.
We know that the state vector is normalized since $\left<1\right|\left.1\right>=1$.
If we are taking a creation operator to this state vector, we obtain $\hat{a}^{\dagger}\left|1\right>=\sqrt{2}\left|2\right>$.
I know the algebra of number states with ladder operators so far.
But, my question is that $\sqrt{2}\left|2\right>$ becomes definitely another quantum state vector but not normalized since $\sqrt{2}\left<2\right|\sqrt{2}\left|2\right>=2\left<2\right|\left.2\right>=2$.
Then, how can I interpret the new quantum state vector which is not normalized?
Is there any formal name referring to the new quantum state vector (not normalized) generated from an operator acting on the original quantum state vector?

Comment: Why should it be normalized in the first place? Take the operator $A=2 \ \boldsymbol 1$, with $\boldsymbol 1$ the identity operator. If you act with $A$ on any normalized vector, the result will not be normalized any more. Only unitary operators conserve normalization; the rest don't.

Comment: Yes, then, what would be the physical meaning of the non-normalized vector in the sense of quantum optics for the former case? As you mentioned, the latter case (unitary operator acting on the normalized vector) physically means "the time evolution of the quantum state vector".

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a physical interpretation because $a^\dagger$ isn't a physical operation. If instead you had a $\pi$-pulse on the $\left|{1}\right\rangle$-$\left|{2}\right\rangle$ transition, you could implement it, and the resulting state would be normalized.